# ansible lookup: issue in displaying as a list

Tags: ansible

I have a var file named prop.yml and contains:

```
var1:
  - 'a'
  - 'b'
var2:
  - 'blah'
  - 'blab'
```

Now, my playbook looks like:

```
 task:
   - name: including a variety file
     include_vars: 
       file: prop.yml
       name: property
   - set_fact:
       project: "{{ lookup ('vars', 'property') }}"

   - debug:
       msg: "{{ project }}"
```

Now, my output is

```
var1[
     "a"
     "b"]
var2[ "blah" , "blab"]
```

What I want as output is

```
 ["a", "b", "blah", "blab"]
```

Comment: Do you want as a result the concatenation or the lists in `var1` and `var2` ?

Comment: Yes, I want the concatenation.

Comment: "How do I concatenate two lists in ansible" is probably more your real question then ;)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the lists.

```
  - debug:
       msg: "{{ project.var1 + project.var2  }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should get you going:

```
  task:
    - name: including a variety file
      include_vars: 
        file: prop.yml
        name: property
    - set_fact:
        project: "{{ property.var1 + property.var2 }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ project }}"
```

Rather than using the vars statically we can concatenate all lists in the included vars file by replacing the set_fact task with the following one.
**This will only work if all declared vars in the file are all lists**. Note the use of the [`default` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#defaulting-undefined-variables) to make sure our result var is always defined. This also uses a [loop over a dict](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-dict)

```
    - name: Iteratively concatenate our lists
      set_fact:
        project: "{{ project | default([]) + item.value }}"
      loop: "{{ property | dict2items }}"
```

Comment: Is there any way to make it dynamic? For example, if tomorrow I add another list in the file, then this script will not work.

Comment: Yes, you can [`loop`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html)